# Determine dates by number of days, "what date is 180 days from now

Tags: sql-server, datetime

How to determine dates by number of days from now - "What date is 180 days from now?"

Answer (score 8):

```
DATEADD(d, 180, GetDate())
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 180, getdate())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getdate() + 180
```

for example:

```
select getdate() as Today, getdate() + 180 as About6MonthsLater
```

Comment: I am currently struggling the dates

Comment: @Kip: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: +1, what I was thinking.  In SQL Server you can use addition and subtraction on DATETIMEs in day increments, with no need for DATEADD()

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want the date, the time part should be stripped out after the calculation is done.

```
SELECT CONVERT (DATETIME, CONVERT (VARCHAR (20), DATEADD(d, 180, GetDate()), 101))
```

Comment: Why use varchar to chop time? It's locale dependent and inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

To find 180 days ahead and remove the time component in one easy go.

No relying on internal implementation (using +) or string handling to chop time.

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 180)
```